# How do I define a SQL Server datatype when I have a bool mapped to SQL Server with Entity Framework?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I have the following in a C# class.

```
    public bool answer1Correct { get; set; }
    public bool answer2Correct { get; set; }
    public bool answer3Correct { get; set; }
    public bool answer4Correct { get; set; }
    public bool answer5Correct { get; set; }
```

I want to use Entity Framework to connect these to a table in SQL Server. What datatype should I use when I create the columns in SQL Server 2012 ?

Comment: sounds like you are using a code first model. If so you shouldn't create the columns. Let EF create your database. If you are concerned about what EF code first will do to your database, look up EF Code First Database Migrations.

Answer (score 12):

Use the datatype BIT ... the Entity Framework will map it correctly

Answer (score 1):

Correct Bit datatype automatically converted into bool.